# What is the shortest text held to be copyrightable?

Tags: united-states, copyright

What is the shortest piece of text for which a copyright holder has won an infringement suit?

Comment: I don't know about texts, but I remember a case where a few notes of a music piece where enough. Don't remember which one, though.

Comment: @PMF: Some examples [here](https://www.bbc.com/culture/article/20190605-nine-most-notorious-copyright-cases-in-music-history).  The one about Vanilla Ice using the "Under Pressure" bass line is 7 notes by my count, on just two different pitches.

Comment: I expect the vast majority of such cases are settled out of court, and since the terms of the settlements are usually not public, it's impossible to say who "won".

Comment: "For sale: baby shoes, never worn." is a six-word story, popularly attributed to Ernest Hemingway (Wikipedia). Still under copyright for a few years.

Comment: @gnasher729 so your comment either is fair use, or is copyright infringement? Has that story actually been held by a court to be under copyright? A search for "for sale baby shoes never worn copyright" didn't find anything.